# Xcode / Swift | Use UIViewController transition for UINavigationController

Tags: swift, xcode

[Storyboard cutting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hro0.png)

The steps that I did were:

1. Create the + and x buttons in the Controllers
2. Create simple outlets in the Controllers
3. Create an action in the Controller for the x (dismiss)-button

   `@IBAction func button_close_pressed(_ sender: Any) {
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }`
4. Create a segue on the Storyboard from the + button to the targetViewController.
5. Create the transition class.

   ```
   import UIKit

   class CircularTransition: NSObject {
       var circle = UIView()
       var startingPoint = CGPoint.zero {
           didSet {
               circle.center = startingPoint
           }
       }
       var circleColor = UIColor.red
       var duration = 3.0
       enum CircularTransitionMode: Int {
           case present, dismiss, pop
       }
       var transitionMode: CircularTransitionMode = .present
   }

   extension CircularTransition: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
       func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
           return duration
       }

       func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
           let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
           if transitionMode == .present {
               if let presentedView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) {
                   let viewCenter = presentedView.center
                   let viewSize = presentedView.frame.size
                   circle = UIView()
                   circle.frame = frameForCircle(withViewCenter: viewCenter, size: viewSize, startPoint: startingPoint)
                   circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.frame.size.height / 2
                   circle.center = startingPoint
                   circle.backgroundColor = circleColor
                   circle.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
                   containerView.addSubview(circle)
                   presentedView.center = startingPoint
                   presentedView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
                   presentedView.alpha = 0
                   containerView.addSubview(presentedView)
                   UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations:     {
                       self.circle.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                       presentedView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                       presentedView.alpha = 1
                       presentedView.center = viewCenter
                   }, completion: { (success: Bool) in
                       transitionContext.completeTransition(success)
                   })
               }
           } else {
               let transitionModeKey = (transitionMode == .pop) ? UITransitionContextViewKey.to : UITransitionContextViewKey.from
               if let returningView = transitionContext.view(forKey: transitionModeKey) {
                   let viewCenter = returningView.center
                   let viewSize = returningView.frame.size
                   circle.frame = frameForCircle(withViewCenter: viewCenter, size: viewSize, startPoint: startingPoint)
                   circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.frame.size.height / 2
                   circle.center = startingPoint
                   UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                       self.circle.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
                       returningView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
                       returningView.center = self.startingPoint
                       returningView.alpha = 0
                       if self.transitionMode == .pop {
                           containerView.insertSubview(returningView, belowSubview: returningView)
                           containerView.insertSubview(self.circle, belowSubview: returningView)
                       }
                   }, completion: { (success: Bool) in
                       returningView.center = viewCenter
                       returningView.removeFromSuperview()
                       self.circle.removeFromSuperview()
                       transitionContext.completeTransition(success)
                   })
               }
           }
       }



       func frameForCircle(withViewCenter viewCenter: CGPoint, size viewSize: CGSize, startPoint: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
           let xLength = fmax(startPoint.x, viewSize.width - startPoint.x)
           let yLength = fmax(startPoint.y, viewSize.height - startPoint.y)
           let offsetVector = sqrt(xLength * xLength + yLength * yLength) * 2
           let size = CGSize(width: offsetVector, height: offsetVector)
           return CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
       }
   }
   ```
6. In the source Controller I added ... to the class

   ```
   UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
   ```
7. Then

   ```
   let transition = CircularTransition()
   ```
8. And last but not least

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       let eventVC = segue.destination as! EventViewController
       eventVC.transitioningDelegate = self
       eventVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
   }

   func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
       transition.transitionMode = .present
       transition.startingPoint = self.button_addEvent.center
       transition.circleColor = self.button_addEvent.backgroundColor!
       return transition
   }

   func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
       transition.transitionMode = .dismiss
       transition.startingPoint = self.button_addEvent.center
       transition.circleColor = self.button_addEvent.backgroundColor!
       return transition
   }
   ```

Now, why doesn't that work? I only can think of that the problem comes with the Navigation Controller instead of a normal ViewController, because with a normal one it works fine. But I really have no idea hwo to change the code to match with the Navigation Controller (source Controller).
Kind regards and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in your viewController

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    switch operation {
      case .push:
        transition.transitionMode = .present
        transition.startingPoint = self.button_addEvent.center
        transition.circleColor = self.button_addEvent.backgroundColor!
        return transition
      default:
        transition.transitionMode = .dismiss
        transition.startingPoint = self.button_addEvent.center
        transition.circleColor = self.button_addEvent.backgroundColor!
        return transition
    }
}
```